# Trouble with an if else if statement c++

Tags: c++

I am working on a grade book project that has 5 students that I want to read the names in for and then with an inner loop grab 4 grades for each student. Something is not working on this loop. This what I am getting:

Please enter the name for student 1: Dave
Please enter the grade number 1 for Dave: 100
Please enter the grade number 2 for Dave: 100
Please enter the grade number 3 for Dave: 100
Please enter the grade number 4 for Dave: 10
Please enter the name for student 2: James
Please enter the grade number 5 for James: 100
Please enter the name for student 3: Sam
Please enter the grade number 5 for Sam: 100
Please enter the name for student 4: Jack
Please enter the grade number 5 for Jack: 100
Please enter the name for student 5: Mike
Please enter the grade number 5 for Mike: 100

It should grab 4 grades before it jumps to the next student. I have not been able to figure this out for the last couple hours. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int STUDENTS = 5; //holds how many students we have
const int SCORES = 4;

void getNames(string names[], double student1[SCORES], double student2[SCORES],
          double student3[SCORES], double student4[SCORES], double student5[SCORES],            int SCORES, int STUDENTS);

int main()
{
    string names[STUDENTS]  = {""};
    char grades[STUDENTS]   = {""};
    double student1[SCORES] = {0};
    double student2[SCORES] = {0};
    double student3[SCORES] = {0};
    double student4[SCORES] = {0};
    double student5[SCORES] = {0};

getNames(names, student1, student2, student3, student4, student5, SCORES,  STUDENTS);


//  Make sure we place the end message on a new line
    cout << endl;

//  The following is system dependent.  It will only work on Windows
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void getNames(string names[], double student1[SCORES], double student2[SCORES],
          double student3[SCORES], double student4[SCORES], double student5[SCORES],     int SCORES, int STUDENTS)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
     {
         cout << "Please enter the name for student " << i+1 << ": ";
         cin >> names[i];
         cout << endl;

         if (i == 0)
         {
            int count1 = 0;
            for (count1; count1 < SCORES; count1++)
            {
                cout << "Please enter the grade number " << count1+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
                cin >> student1[count1];
                cout << endl;
            }
         }
         else if (i == 1)
         {
            int count2 = 0; 
            for (count2; count2 < SCORES; count2++);
            {
                cout << "Please enter the grade number " << count2+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
                cin >> student2[count2];
                cout << endl;
            }
         }
         else if (i == 2)
         {
            int count3 = 0; 
            for (count3; count3 < SCORES; count3++);
            {
                cout << "Please enter the grade number " << count3+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
                cin >> student3[count3];
                cout << endl;
            }
         }
         else if (i == 3)
         {
            int count4 = 0; 
            for (count4; count4 < SCORES; count4++);
            {
                cout << "Please enter the grade number " << count4+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
                cin >> student4[count4];
                cout << endl;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            int count5 = 0; 
            for (count5; count5 < SCORES; count5++);
            {
                cout << "Please enter the grade number " << count5+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
                cin >> student5[count5];
                cout << endl;
            }
         }

     }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Why do you have arrays student1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of an array of students? Especially since you KNOW about arrays... (Yes, you can have arrays of arrays, arrays of structs, whatever you want)

Comment: Why even have the loop if you're going to have that big if/else inside of it?

Comment: I believe you have not yet grasped the concept of a loop.

Comment: the project requires me to have five arrays of four doubles to hold each students test score.

Comment: Two nested for loops is all you need - get rid of all those ifs and use an array of struct - name, 4 grades . Much, much simpler.

Comment: "The project requires"... So have an array of pointers to the five arrays - this is a clumsy way of making a 2d array and it still takes just two nested for loops.

Comment: `std::array<std::array<double,SCORES>,STUDENTS>`

Comment: You all got hung up on style and forgot to answer the question.  The problem is the trailing semi-colons.  All style-related comments should be secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some pretty rough stuff going on in here, but the problem is that you have a semi-colon on all your inner loops except the first one:

```
for (count2; count2 < SCORES; count2++);
```

Remove the semi-colon, and the stuff in the braces will become part of the loop.

I'm going to suggest you make your code a little tidier and less error-prone by chucking all those function arguments into their own array when you enter the function, like this:

```
double *scores[5] = { student1, student2, student3, student4, student5 };
```

Then you take OUT all that repetition - the copy/paste is what caused your problems to begin with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter the name for student " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> names[i];
    cout << endl;

    for (int s = 0; s < SCORES; s++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the grade number " << s+1 << " for " << names[i] <<": ";
        cin >> scores[i][s];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Yes it looks rough, it got rougher and rougher as time passed and I didn't find that silly ; error. Thanks for the help, now time to follow your advice and tidy it up a bit.

Comment: No problem.  Just some general advice, you should have immediately questioned how the value of `count2` could start at `4` when you ask for the grades.  The trailing semi-colon (empty for-loop) thing is a devious and hard-to-spot problem, but questioning your output should have taken you straight to the source.  A few experiments (such as switching the `(i==0)` and `(i==1)` conditions would have pinpointed that loop as problematic, and you could then try comparing it character-by-character with the working one in order to quickly find the problem.  Anyway, happy coding =)

Comment: Thanks paddy, I am always thankful to learn new ways to trouble shoot. I am in Programming Fundamentals 1 and don't get much trouble shooting in class it is pretty much learn by doing at home. Thanks again. Also thanks to all the other people that offered a solution I try all of them to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use two nested loops like

```
  for (int studix=0, stduix<STUDENTS; studix++) { 
     //...
     for (int gradix=0; gradix<SCORE; gradix++) {
        //...
     }
     //....
  }
```

BTW, the condition could be a more complex one, e.g. with the internal loop being

```
     bool goodgrade=true;
     for (int gradix=0; goodgrade && gradix<SCORE; gradix++) {
       // you could modify goodgrade or use break; inside the loop
     }
```

Don't forget the possible use of `continue` and `break` inside a loop.

And please, take time to **read some good C++ programming book**

Comment: the project specifically calls for the use of the 5 arrays holding the 4 grades. I don't see how a nested loop would help me their since I have no way of telling the loop now it is the next arrays turn. Or am I missing somethin? I know there is easier ways of doing this but those are the guidelines I am supposed to code this program by.

Comment: I think you will need to show how to index inside that inner loop since "the project requires" the use of five arrays. Looks like `double *gradeArray[STUDENTS];` is part of a solution. Then `gradeArray[0]=student1; ` etc.

Comment: Do you know about the `break` and `continue` statements

Comment: yes break takes me out of the if statement and continue moves to next iteration. let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Basile's answer and my comments:

```
int main()
{
string names[STUDENTS]  = {""};
char grades[STUDENTS]   = {""};
double student1[SCORES] = {0};
double student2[SCORES] = {0};
double student3[SCORES] = {0};
double student4[SCORES] = {0};
double student5[SCORES] = {0};

double *gradeArray[STUDENTS];
gradeArray[0] = student1;
gradeArray[1] = student2;
gradeArray[2] = student3;
gradeArray[3] = student4;
gradeArray[4] = student5;

for (int studix=0, stduix<STUDENTS; studix++) { 
 // get the name of the student
 for (int gradix=0; gradix<SCORE; gradix++) {
    // put the grades in gradeArray[studix][gradix]...

 }
 //....
}
```

Yes, I know about 2 D arrays, but I am trying to make explicit how this can be done with "five individual arrays". Clumsy, but I believe this works.

Comment: when you are doing double *gradeArray[STUDENTS]; what does the * do to the array? Sorry for the stupid question I am in Programming Fundamentals 1 and have not gotten to that yet.

Comment: Same thing that @paddy did in his answer... I declare an "array of pointers" - since the "name" of an array is actually a pointer. So when you have `double student1[5]`, `student1` is actually a pointer (to the first element). When you create an array of pointers, you can "pick which array to use" - in my example, gradeArray[2] points to the start of `student3`, so `gradeArray[2][3]` is the 4th grade of student 3 (remember arrays start at zero). Does that explain it for you?

Comment: Just to clarify: `double *anything` declares `anything` to be of the type `pointer to double`. And pointers and arrays have a very intimate relationship - this is critical to understanding a lot of C (and C++) code, and well worth getting your brain around. A common mistake is using pointers without making sure that they point to a valid address - memory set aside for you. This is done automatically for you when you declare `double myArray[5]` - but a lot of power is unlocked by really understanding what pointers do.

Comment: our teacher keeps telling us that it really gets fun when we talk about pointer but we just got done with arrays and not much hope that we will make to pointers this semester looks like I will have to figure this out on my own. I am starting to see that pointers make thinks easier.

Comment: Yes - it does get fun. A little confusing at first, but fun. It's one of those things you just have to start using, and suddenly it clicks. But you will have a few SEGFAULTS before you really get it. We've all been there. Definitely worth the effort, though! But when you are using arrays, you are already using pointers - you just don't know it. `myArray[2]` is actually the same as `*(myArray + 2)`. ("the element you get when you point two locations past the point where `myArray` is pointing). Lots of learn - have fun on the journey!